# Web scraping from Amazon is generating an error

Tags: python-requests

I've been trying to perform web scraping on an Amazon product to extract the price. I've only used Requests to try to fetch the page data, but I always get the same error:

"To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_c_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac for advertising use cases.

Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies."

What can I do?

```
import requests

header = { 
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "Referer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Revlon-One-Step-Volumizer-PLUS/dp/B096SVJZSW/?_encoding=UTF8&content-id=amzn1.sym.3f4ca281-e55c-46d1-9425-fb252d20366f&ref_=pd_gw_exports_top_sellers_unrec'

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

data=response.text
print(data)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Amazon has probably flagged you IP for scraping. Try a VPN and send requests at brief intervals. Try rotating IPs with VPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon adds cookies when you browse them to assure you work though a browser (just go into browsers developer mode and look at application/Cookies)

If you use requests directly it will not return any cookies:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
s = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Revlon-One-Step-Volumizer-PLUS/dp/B096SVJZSW/?_encoding=UTF8&content-id=amzn1.sym.3f4ca281-e55c-46d1-9425-fb252d20366f&ref_=pd_gw_exports_top_sellers_unrec"
r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

`{}`

So amazon has something in place to prevent python requests to work, even if you manipulate User-Agent.

Options:

1 - Amazon has a price api - https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/product-pricing-api-v0-reference#getpricing with 0.5 queries per sec max rate in free usage plan.
But this is recommended compared to a slow browser.

2 - You can use browsers, it is rather slow. But working with playwright is so fun:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

url = "https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Revlon-One-Step-Volumizer-PLUS/dp/B096SVJZSW/?_encoding=UTF8&content-id=amzn1.sym.3f4ca281-e55c-46d1-9425-fb252d20366f&ref_=pd_gw_exports_top_sellers_unrec"

with sync_playwright() as p:
    t0 = time.time()
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True) # just so you know how to get it headfull for debugging
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(url)
    #print(page.title())
    price = page.locator("(//span[@class='a-price a-text-price']/span[@class='a-offscreen'])[1]").text_content()
    print(f"{price} in {time.time()-t0:.2f}sec")
    #page.pause() #do not close browser in full mode for debug
    browser.close()
```

`US$39.97 in 10.26sec`

https://playwright.dev/python/

Comment: Or you can use this package https://pypi.org/project/scrape-amazon/

Comment: What does Amazon have in place to prevent requests from working? I've tried using requests even with cookies and header directly from the browser but it doesn't work.

Comment: do the prices also get updated at instant with amazon's api (for example if a vendor discounts its price, does api also update it instantly ? )